# JSF 2.0 @ManagedProperty returns null value

Tags: jsf-2

l've some trouble with injecting one managedbean in another by defining a managedproperty.But the property is null. can anybody tell me, why my property is null?
UserLoginBean.java

```
    @RequestScoped
public class UserLoginBean extends AbstractMB implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String username;
        private String password;
//getter and setter
        public void login() throws ServletException, IOException{
    try
    {
      ExternalContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext(); 
      HttpServletRequest request = ((HttpServletRequest)context.getRequest());

      ServletResponse resposnse = ((ServletResponse)context.getResponse());
      RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/j_spring_security_check");
      dispatcher.forward(request, resposnse);
      FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();
     }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        displayErrorMessageToUser("Login or Password Failed");
    }
```

ReclamationMB.java

```
@RequestScoped
public class ReclamationMB extends AbstractMB implements Serializable {
...
@ManagedProperty("#{loginBean}")
    private UserLoginBean userLogin;
/getter and setter
```

But in .xhtml it is not null, it return the username:

```
<h:outputText value="#{loginBean.username}
```

Comment: Since there are not in the code... does the property have a setter defined?

Comment: @SJuan76 OP wrote `getter and setter` in his code

Comment: yes it have a setter and getter in the two class

Comment: Have you annotated your managed beans with:
@ManagedBean
?

Comment: i declared it in the faces-config.xml <managed-bean>
  <managed-bean-name>reclamationMB</managed-bean-name>
  <managed-bean-class>com.progress.hotline.managedbean.ReclamationMB</managed-bean-class>
  <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
 </managed-bean> <managed-bean>
  <managed-bean-name>loginBean</managed-bean-name>
  <managed-bean-class>com.progress.hotline.managedbean.UserLoginBean</managed-bean-class>
  <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
 </managed-bean>

Comment: Are you requesting UserLoginBean in the same .xhtml that you're requesting ReclamationMB? It seems that only ReclamationMB is requested, so UserLoginBean will be `null`, since it is @RequestScoped. Just guessing.

Comment: Does it work if you specify the managed property in the reclamationMB in the faces-config.xml rather than using the annotation?

Comment: post faces-config.xml here

Comment: @DiogoMoreira thnx very mutch

Answer (score 0):

Is userLogin in ReclamationMB null or is the username null? If userLogin is not null, the injection works fine, but the bean is newly created as it's Requestscoped. 
You can either put UserLoginBean into Viewscope to prevent recreating the bean:

```
@ViewScoped
 public class UserLoginBean extends AbstractMB implements Serializable{...}
```

Or you can fill the data which is needed for userLogin manually in ReclamationsMB by providing a PostConstruct method

```
@RequestScoped
 public class ReclamationMB extends AbstractMB implements Serializable {
 ...
 @ManagedProperty("#{loginBean}")
 private UserLoginBean userLogin; //getter and setter

 @PostConstruct
 public void init() {
   //Call Bean methods or set variables manually
   userLogin.setUsername(...);
 }
```

Comment: No , the userLogin wich is null.